# Print the xpath expression from a compiled javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression object

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible to print the string pattern from an compiled xPathExpression object?

It might be needed for cases where the expression is compiled at one point in time. but evaluated multiple times at a later point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XPathExppression` does not have an method to do that. (`XPathExppression.toString` does also not return anything meaningful for the default JDK implementation).

If you control the creation of the expression you could create a wrapper class which keeps the expression string and returns that string when `toString()` is called.

```
String exprString = ...;
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(exprString);
WrapperXPathExpr proxyExpr = new WrapperXPathExpr(expr, exprString);
```

and the wrapper class could look like

```
public class WrapperXPathExpr implements XPathExpression {
    private XPathExpression expr_;
    private String exprString_;

    public WrapperXPathExpr(XPathExpression expr, String exprString) {
         expr_ = expr;
         exprString_ = exprString;
    }

    public Object evaluate(Object item, QName returnType) throws XPathExpressionException {
         return expr_.evaluate(item, returnType);
    }

    ...

    public String toString() {
        return exprString_;
    }
}
```